# API CSRF protection

Tags: api, security, csrf, csrf-protection

I have an app that consists of simple JSON API and React frontend. Authentication is handled via cookies and frontend is served from the same domain I use for API. Since I don't allow CORS, wonder if API is going to be protected against CSRF attacks if it accepts only requests with some custom header, for example if `X-Requested-With` is set to `XMLHttpRequest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attacker can send a cross-site request with an `XMLHttpRequest` without violation the Same-Origin Policy (SOP) - the only limit here is that the attacker's site won't be able to see the response. Cookies are included with every request sent by the victim's browser so the API call will still fire with a cross-site XHR, so this API is still vulnerable to CSRF.

If you don't want to make any security architecture changes, then the [CSRF Prevention Cheat Sheet recommends checking the Origin header](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Verifying_Same_Origin_with_Standard_Headers). This document describes other methods, such as the CSRF token synchronizer method which could be used as a header element and is considered a stronger method of defense.

Comment: thanks rook. i verified this with two apps running on localhost but different ports. I couldn't destroy a resource on app1 with cross site DELETE request from app2, but I was able to create one with POST. My understanding was that, in order to check is it allowed to send xhr, only http option request is going to be sent in all cases.

Comment: @rodic for the love of all that is right in the world please at the very minimum check the `Origin` - i assure you this is exploitable.  The options pre-flight can be avoided.

Comment: hey in case it's not clear i'll take your advice from the original post. just wanted to verify what you said because i thought sop works differently. thanks again.